# Issue Caching Tweets with PHP

Tags: php, json, caching, twitter

I've been using various pieces of different twitter feeds to grab tweets, but now I've hit a wall with the rate limiting and caching tweets. Here's my code:

```
function tweets($twitter_handle, $tweet_limit, $tweet_links, $tweet_tags, $tweet_avatar,   $tweet_profile) {

    /* Store Tweets in a JSON object */
    $tweet_feed =   json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name='.
                    $twitter_handle.'&include_entities=true&include_rts=true&count='.$hard_max.''));
```

This works great until I hit the rate limit. Here's what I added to cache tweets:

```
function tweets($twitter_handle, $tweet_limit, $tweet_links, $tweet_tags, $tweet_avatar, $tweet_profile) {

$url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name='.$twitter_handle.'&include_entities=true&include_rts=true&count='.$hard_max.'';
$cache = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cache/twitter';

if(filemtime($cache) < (time() - 60))
{
    mkdir(dirname(__FILE__) . '/cache', 0777);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $cachefile = fopen($cache, 'wb');
    fwrite($cachefile, $data);
    fclose($cachefile);
}
else
{
    $data = file_get_contents($cache);
}

$tweet_feed = json_decode($data);
```

This however only returns the username and timestamp (which is wrong), when it should be returning the twitter avatar, tweet content, correct timestamp, etc. Additionally, it's also returning an error every few refreshes:

> Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: File exists in /home/content/36/8614836/html/wp-content/themes/NCmainSite/functions.php on line 110

Any help would be appreciated.
If you need more info, here's the rest of the function: http://snippi.com/s/9f066q0

Comment: The mkdir error is obvious enough - you're trying to create the cache dir EVERYTIME this function runs. You should check if the directory exists BEFORE trying to create it.

Comment: Add `@` before `mkdir()` to mute the warning. Or check if it exists using `is_dir()` before calling `mkdir()`.

Comment: Don't ever use error suppression. If you're getting a warning, fix it.

Comment: $hard_max is set in a separate file. I'm going to eventually use Wordpress' theme options to set the $hard_max. Everything about this works great until I attempt to cache.

Comment: @MarcB thanks for the tip - but this doesn't speak to the greater problem of the contents of the tweet not appearing, does it?

Comment: @NeilAitken Error-suppression can be useful to prevent race conditions. [I found this post interesting](http://blog.rodneyrehm.de/archives/12-Improving-Disk-IO-in-PHP-Apps.html).

Comment: @florent: using `@` to suppress errors and warnings is generally a bad thing.

Comment: @lukad03: which is why it was a comment, and not an answer.

Comment: @arxanas Please correct me if I'm mistaken, but that doesn't actually prevent the race condition, it just silences it.

Comment: @NeilAitken The whole problem with the race condition is that there are two calls — one to `is_dir` and one to `mkdir`. In such a scenario, something could happen to the directory *in between* the two calls. By calling only `@mkdir`, there is no opportunity for other sources to change the file hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this ive fixed your issues, plus you had a rogue post opt in curl.

```
<?php 
function tweets($twitter_handle, $tweet_limit, $tweet_links, $tweet_tags, $tweet_avatar, $tweet_profile) {

    $http_query = array('screen_name'=>$twitter_handle,
                        'include_entities'=>'true',
                        'include_rts'=>'true',
                        'count'=>(isset($hard_max))?$hard_max:'5');

    $url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?'.http_build_query($http_query);

    $cache_folder = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cache';
    $cache_file = $cache_folder . '/twitter.json';

    //Check folder exists
    if(!file_exists($cache_folder)){mkdir($cache_folder, 0777);}

    //Do if cache files not found or older then 60 seconds (tho 60 is not enough)
    if(!file_exists($cache_file) || filemtime($cache_file) < (time() - 60)){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        file_put_contents($cache_file,$data);
    }else{
        $data = file_get_contents($cache_file);
    }

    return json_decode($data);
}

$twitter = tweets('RemotiaSoftware', 'tweet_limit','tweet_links', 'tweet_tags', 'tweet_avatar', 'tweet_profile');
print_r($twitter);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I added some edits to work with my included function.